# Why we don't use always inclusive or?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics

Consider that the following is always true. "If A then B XOR C".

If we change exclusive *or* to inclusive *or*, then the following statement also holds, because every time exclusive *or* is true, the same holds for inclusive. We make this distinction because it maybe not clear that B and C can't both be true?

Comment: In most cases the term OR expresses the inclusive context. In your example you explicitly state XOR which is very specific. You should not ignore the specific details. An exclusive or expresses that both disjuncts cannot be true simultaneously. Only one alternative can be accepted.  Choosing one alternative immediately disqualifies the other alternative. Had you stated only OR in the example we would take it to mean inclusive OR. That is all three variables could possibly be true: A,B as well as C simultaneously. The example you gave prohibits a, b & c all being true simultaneously.

Comment: I don't understand what the body of the question has to do with title. The answer to the title question is that we sometimes intend to mean exclusive or -- is that so hard to see?

Answer (score 2):

Exclusive or is more demanding ; so you can't substitute inclusive or for exclusive or.

As you can see by observing ther truth tables, exclusive or is true in only 2 cases out of 4, while inclusive or is true in 3 cases out of 4.

So an exclusve  or statement is much more precise (25% more precise, so to say).

Same case, for example, with & and -->.

Every time (A&B) is true (A-->B) is also true.

So why using  (A&B)?

Precisely because sometimes , we want to express something that has more demanding truth conditions than (A --> B).

Example :

If you ask a person the question : " is it true you've lived in Japan and (that) you know japaneese language"?

you probably will not be satisfied with an answer such as : "yes, if I've lived in Japan, then I know japaneese language".

The fact that you used the & operator makes your question much more demanding.

The answer you have received is true in 3 cases out of 4, while an appropriate positive answer to your question is true in only one case.

Comment: In your third paragraph I think you mean that an *exclusive* or statement is more precise: "p XOR q" says more than "p OR q."

Comment: you were right, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Even ignoring the issue of strength - namely (per Ray LittleRock's answer) that XOR is often more appropriate when we want to "say more," that is, make an assertion which is true under fewer circumstances* - there's a serious issue here: contra your claim in the OP, it's **not** always true that we can replace "XOR" with "OR" in a true statement and wind up with another true statement.

For example,

> (p XOR q) implies r

can be true without

> (p OR q) implies r

being true: take r to be ~(p AND q).

Note that what's changed between this and your example is **where** we've placed the disjunction in the implication, namely in the hypothesis versus in the conclusion. Implication, unlike AND, OR, and XOR, is **not commutative**.

So even if we ignore the fact that XOR often lets us make stronger claims, it's not the case that we can always safely replace it with OR.

---

*This isn't directly relevant to your question, but I think it's too neat not to observe:

The connection here between *what a statement says* and *the conditions under which that statement is true* - which we're using to connect "says more" and "is less frequently true" - is one of those things which is deceptively deep: my experience is that for most people it's obviously true, then it's obviously false, then it's weird and confusing ... and then it's obviously true again - except when it's not ... In my opinion **no part** of this connection is trivial or uninteresting. Both arguments for and against it (can) have a lot of content, even if only implicitly, and especially in mathematical logic the issue develops some really cool nuances. *(I've said a little about this in the context of Venn diagrams [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2560346/28111).)*